# how to animatecamera with latlng bounds and centre at particular lat lng

Tags: android, google-maps

Currently I am working on app in which I have to represent an array of markers on the map at different lat lng. The problem faced by me now is each time(at fixed interval) I animate camera by bounding lat lngs of these markers, camera starting to move center towards the nearest marker. What I want is to always focus my camera focus to center to given lat lng, how can I do it?

Comment: make your question more clear

Comment: I have 10 markers in the GoogleMap. I want to zoom in as much as possible and keep all markers in view with  camera centering to fixed lat lng position

Answer (score -1):

In this sample code , i just created five markers, then i added animation to the center most latlng . So the camera will zoom to the latlng3 and othe latlngs should be surrounded with the center one. it will zoom upto level 7 within 3 seconds.

this worked for me very well.

```
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng1).title("Marker Title1")).showInfoWindow();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng2).title("Marker Title2")).showInfoWindow();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng3).title("Marker Title3")).showInfoWindow();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng4).title("Marker Title4")).showInfoWindow();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng5).title("Marker Title15n")).showInfoWindow();

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng3));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(7), 3000, null);
```

refer here for more details

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views

Comment: but this does not show all markers within the latlng bounds

Comment: I have 10 markers in the GoogleMap. I want to zoom in as much as possible and keep all markers in view with  camera centering to fixed lat lng position

Comment: @  Rubin Nellikunnathu have u seen the app of uber, I want to work my map like same when I select any cabs